# How to fill in missing rows in a table with default values in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns (`a`, `b`, `c`) and I want to make sure that for each possible combination of values in the first two columns, there is a row containing that combination. For example if this is my table:

```
  a   b   c
 --- --- ---
  P   X   1
  Q   Y   2
  Q   Z   3
  R   Y   4
  S   Y   5
  S   Z   6
```

The unique values in column `a` are `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, and the unique values in column `b` are `X`, `Y`, `Z`. So I want to create a query that returns 12 rows (4×3) that fills in missing values in column `c` with a default value like 0, for example:

```
  a   b   c
 --- --- ---
  P   X   1
  P   Y   0
  P   Z   0
  Q   X   0
  Q   Y   2
  Q   Z   3
  R   X   0
  R   Y   4
  R   Z   0
  S   X   0
  S   Y   5
  S   Z   6
```

The way I'm currently doing it is this:

```
select a, b, ifnull(c, 0)
from (select distinct a from table),
     (select distinct b from table)
     left join table using (a, b)
```

Unfortunately, this query is very slow since the table contains like ten thousand rows. If I precompute the query and store it in a table, then accessing the results is faster, but it takes a lot of space, most of which is probably just filled with zeros in the `c` column. Is there any way to make this query faster?

Comment: I don't know of a way to speed up a `cartesian product`.  There are some decent comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42174651/1073631.  Which is more of a concern to you, performance or disk space?

Comment: Performance is more of a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
select a.a, b.b, coalesce(c.c, 0)
from (select distinct a from table) a cross join
     (select distinct b from table) b left join
     table c
     using (a, b);
```

You want indexes on:

- `(a, b)`
- `(b)`

The first index can be used for the `select distinct a` and for the `join`.  The second can be used for the `select distinct b`.